# Convert Hash to OpenStruct recursively

Tags: ruby

Given I have this hash:

```
 h = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: { d: 'd', e: 'e'} }
```

And I convert to OpenStruct:

```
o = OpenStruct.new(h)
 => #<OpenStruct a="a", b="b", c={:d=>"d", :e=>"e"}> 
o.a
 => "a" 
o.b
 => "b" 
o.c
 => {:d=>"d", :e=>"e"} 
2.1.2 :006 > o.c.d
NoMethodError: undefined method `d' for {:d=>"d", :e=>"e"}:Hash
```

I want all the nested keys to be methods as well. So I can access `d` as such:

```
o.c.d
=> "d"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you like OpenStruct you'll love [Hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie).

Comment: @donato I know this is an old question. But please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809848/convert-hash-to-object/52745801#52745801 and let me know if that helps.

Comment: I've created a PR  https://github.com/ruby/ostruct/pull/5 for openstruct to include this in the library itself. Please support it if you think it will help others like you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert hash to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809848/convert-hash-to-object)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

personally I use the `recursive-open-struct` gem - it's then as simple as `RecursiveOpenStruct.new(<nested_hash>)`

But for the sake of recursion practice, I'll show you a fresh solution:

```
require 'ostruct'

def to_recursive_ostruct(hash)
  result = hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, val), memo|
    memo[key] = val.is_a?(Hash) ? to_recursive_ostruct(val) : val
  end
  OpenStruct.new(result)
end

puts to_recursive_ostruct(a: { b: 1}).a.b
# => 1
```

*edit*

Weihang Jian showed a slight improvement to this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69311716/2981429

```
def to_recursive_ostruct(hash)
  hash.each_with_object(OpenStruct.new) do |(key, val), memo|
    memo[key] = val.is_a?(Hash) ? to_recursive_ostruct(val) : val
  end
end
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63264908/2981429 which shows how to handle arrays

*note*

the reason this is better than the JSON-based solutions is because you can lose some data when you convert to JSON. For example if you convert a Time object to JSON and then parse it, it will be a string. There are many other examples of this:

```
class Foo; end
JSON.parse({obj: Foo.new}.to_json)["obj"]
# => "#<Foo:0x00007fc8720198b0>"
```

yeah ... not super useful. You've completely lost your reference to the actual instance.

Comment: i used your answer and works well with hash, what about if having array value with hash inside e.g. { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: [{ d: 'd', e: 'e'}] }, so I can do c.d => 'd'
Thanks :)

Comment: @aldrien.h If you had `{c: [{d: 'd'}]}` why would you want to use `c.d`? How would that work if you had multiple hashes in the array?

Comment: my mistake, i forgot to say, it inside a loop :)

Comment: The `JSON.parse` answer is far more flexible and elegant.

Comment: @TončiD. it's really not. The problem is that not everything can be converted to JSON and keep its same Ruby class. For example `JSON.parse({now: Time.now}.to_json)["now"].class == String` ... The `Time.now` is no longer a `Time` object when you parse/unparse it.

Comment: @maxpleaner Agreed. I was biased towards what worked for my situation.

Comment: @maxpleaner adding this line below `memo[key] = ...` would take care of arrays:

`memo[key] = val.map { |v| v.is_a?(Hash) ? to_recursive_ostruct(v) : v } if val.is_a?(Array)`

Comment: You can recurse over arrays: `RecursiveOpenStruct.new(h, recurse_over_arrays: true)`

Answer (score 53):

You can monkey-patch the `Hash` class

```
class Hash
  def to_o
    JSON.parse to_json, object_class: OpenStruct
  end
end
```

then you can say

```
h = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: { d: 'd', e: 'e'} }
o = h.to_o
o.c.d # => 'd'
```

See [Convert a complex nested hash to an object](https://coderwall.com/p/74rajw/convert-a-complex-nested-hash-to-an-object).

Comment: Been using Ruby for over 10 years and I'm still surprised by its elegance.

Comment: Though it should work to solve the problem, but this process has some side-effects like it will change the default `Hash` behavior in all places in the project, which might create unforeseen issues in coming days. So I would rather go with max_pleaner or Donato 
 `JSON.parse(h.to_json, object_class: OpenStruct)`which seems to solve the issue in place without side-effects.

Comment: FYI this only works with simple values. I had issues when I applied this  approach to more complex objects (e.g. BigDecimal or custom ActiveRecord objects)

Comment: yes it changes values of symbol to string

Answer (score 35):

I came up with this solution:

```
h = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: { d: 'd', e: 'e'} }
json = h.to_json
=> "{\"a\":\"a\",\"b\":\"b\",\"c\":{\"d\":\"d\",\"e\":\"e\"}}" 
object = JSON.parse(json, object_class:OpenStruct)
object.c.d
 => "d"
```

So for this to work, I had to do an extra step: convert it to json.

Comment: Messy, but functional. There's better ways though.

Comment: Dependencies? Openstruct and Json are part of the standard library.

Comment: Nice, this seems to work well. One difference I encountered is I had to call `object.table.c.d`.

Comment: I believe generating json just to parse it is not very efficient approach

Comment: when a value is a symbol, it converts it to a string

Answer (score 9):

Here's a recursive solution that avoids converting the hash to json:

```rb
def to_o(obj)
  if obj.is_a?(Hash)
    return OpenStruct.new(obj.map{ |key, val| [ key, to_o(val) ] }.to_h)
  elsif obj.is_a?(Array)
    return obj.map{ |o| to_o(o) }
  else # Assumed to be a primitive value
    return obj
  end
end
```

Comment: as each_with_object is deprecated, for me this is the best solution

Comment: @ChristianoMatos Can you give some references about the deprecation? I don't see any evidence.

Answer (score 3):

My solution, based on [max pleaner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42520668/2630849) and similar to [Xavi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57262111/2630849):

```ruby
require 'ostruct'

def initialize_open_struct_deeply(value)
  case value
  when Hash
    OpenStruct.new(value.transform_values { |hash_value| send __method__, hash_value })
  when Array
    value.map { |element| send __method__, element }
  else
    value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution is cleaner and faster than @max-pleaner's.

I don't actually know why but I don't instance extra Hash objects:

```rb
def dot_access(hash)
  hash.each_with_object(OpenStruct.new) do |(key, value), struct|
    struct[key] = value.is_a?(Hash) ? dot_access(value) : value
  end
end
```

Here is the benchmark for you reference:

```rb
require 'ostruct'

def dot_access(hash)
  hash.each_with_object(OpenStruct.new) do |(key, value), struct|
    struct[key] = value.is_a?(Hash) ? dot_access(value) : value
  end
end

def to_recursive_ostruct(hash)
  result = hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, val), memo|
    memo[key] = val.is_a?(Hash) ? to_recursive_ostruct(val) : val
  end
  OpenStruct.new(result)
end

require 'benchmark/ips'
Benchmark.ips do |x|
  hash = { a: 1, b: 2, c: { d: 3 } }
  x.report('dot_access') { dot_access(hash) }
  x.report('to_recursive_ostruct') { to_recursive_ostruct(hash) }
end
```

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
          dot_access     4.843k i/100ms
to_recursive_ostruct     5.218k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
          dot_access     51.976k (± 5.0%) i/s -    261.522k in   5.044482s
to_recursive_ostruct     50.122k (± 4.6%) i/s -    250.464k in   5.008116s
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to override the initializer so you can do `OpenStruct.new({ a: "b", c: { d: "e", f: ["g", "h", "i"] }})`.

Further, this class is included when you `require 'json'`, so be sure to do this patch after the `require`.

```rb
class OpenStruct
  def initialize(hash = nil)
    @table = {}
    if hash
      hash.each_pair do |k, v|
        self[k] = v.is_a?(Hash) ? OpenStruct.new(v) : v
      end
    end
  end

  def keys
    @table.keys.map{|k| k.to_s}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing a conversion on OpenStruct works fine until it doesn't.  For instance, none of the other answers here properly handle these simple hashes:

```
people = { person1: { display: { first: 'John' } } }
creds = { oauth: { trust: true }, basic: { trust: false } }
```

The method below works with those hashes, modifying the input hash rather than returning a new object.

```
def add_indifferent_access!(hash)
  hash.each_pair do |k, v|
    hash.instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v.tap { |v| send(__method__, v) if v.is_a?(Hash) } )
    hash.define_singleton_method(k, proc { hash.instance_variable_get("@#{k}") } )
  end
end
```

then

```
add_indifferent_access!(people)
people.person1.display.first # => 'John'
```

Or if your context calls for a more inline call structure:

```
creds.yield_self(&method(:add_indifferent_access!)).oauth.trust # => true
```

Alternatively, you could mix it in:

```
module HashExtension
  def very_indifferent_access!
    each_pair do |k, v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v.tap { |v| v.extend(HashExtension) && v.send(__method__) if v.is_a?(Hash) } )
      define_singleton_method(k, proc { self.instance_variable_get("@#{k}") } )
    end
  end
end
```

and apply to individual hashes:

```
favs = { song1: { title: 'John and Marsha', author: 'Stan Freberg' } }
favs.extend(HashExtension).very_indifferent_access!
favs.song1.title
```

Here is a variation for monkey-patching Hash, should you opt to do so:

```
class Hash
  def with_very_indifferent_access!
    each_pair do |k, v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v.tap { |v| v.send(__method__) if v.is_a?(Hash) } )
      define_singleton_method(k, proc { instance_variable_get("@#{k}") } )
    end
  end
end
# Note the omission of "v.extend(HashExtension)" vs. the mix-in variation.
```

Comments to other answers expressed a desire to retain class types.  This solution accommodates that.

```
people = { person1: { created_at: Time.now } }
people.with_very_indifferent_access!
people.person1.created_at.class # => Time
```

Whatever solution you choose, I recommend testing with this hash:

`people = { person1: { display: { first: 'John' } }, person2: { display: { last: 'Jingleheimer' } } }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with monkey-patching the Hash class, you can do:

```
require 'ostruct'

module Structurizable
  def each_pair(&block)
    each do |k, v|
      v = OpenStruct.new(v) if v.is_a? Hash

      yield k, v
    end
  end
end

Hash.prepend Structurizable

people = { person1: { display: { first: 'John' } }, person2: { display: { last: 'Jingleheimer' } } }

puts OpenStruct.new(people).person1.display.first
```

Ideally, instead of pretending this, we should be able to use a Refinement, but for some reason I can't understand it didn't worked for the each_pair method (also, unfortunately Refinements are still pretty limited)