# Construct nested OpenStruct object

Tags: ruby, openstruct

I have to mimic a Google API response and create a 2-level deep data structure that is traversable by `.` like this:

```
=> user.names.first_name
```

> Bob

Is there any smarter/better way than this:

```
 user = OpenStruct.new(names: OpenStruct.new(first_name: 'Bob'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Hash to OpenStruct recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519557/convert-hash-to-openstruct-recursively)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This method is rude method but works,

```
require 'ostruct'
require 'json'
# Data in hash
data = {"names" => {"first_name" => "Bob"}}
result = JSON.parse(data.to_json, object_class: OpenStruct)
```

And another method is adding method to Hash class itself,

```
class Hash
  def to_openstruct
    JSON.parse to_json, object_class: OpenStruct
  end
end
```

Using above method you can convert your hash to openstruct

```
data = {"names" => {"first_name" => "Bob"}}
data.to_openstruct
```

Comment: I feel like I've been looking for this answer for ten years...thank you!

Comment: In a gist: https://gist.github.com/smtlaissezfaire/ad1fbf6d2f765208a3de2b0ab9721e24

Comment: Note that it gets funky if you try to nest a deep_openstruct instead another deep_openstruct