# Accessing nested hashes with accessors in ruby

Tags: ruby

So I have a hash:

```
a = {
    foo: {
        bar: 1
    }
}
```

Now I can access value 1 with `a[:foo][:bar]`.

How would I go on about generating methods from this automatically so I could access the value with `a.foo.bar`?
Is this even possible? If it is how could I generate this for a predetermined hash?

Comment: It's possible, but you realize that `a.foo` is not just a part of a path, right ?

Comment: See my answer on a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42520668/2981429

Comment: found it. added some info here too.

Answer (score -1):

This is doable with https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html from the standard library.
To make this work recursively we can use:

```
require 'ostruct'

def to_os(obj)
  case obj
  when Hash
    OpenStruct.new(obj.transform_values { |h| to_os(h) })
  when Array
    obj.map { |o| to_os(o) }
  else
    obj
  end
end

a = { foo: { bar: 1 } }
b = to_os(a)

puts b[:foo]
puts b.foo
puts b[:foo][:bar]
```

But as noted in the comments this becomes an OpenStruct, which means that the output of the upper code is:

```
#<OpenStruct bar=1>
#<OpenStruct bar=1>
1
```

So what we deduce from this that the nested hash gets lost.

Comment: This question fails its own premise. An OpenStuct is not a hash. Its an object that wraps a hash with dynamic accessors.